# Excel add-on, manifest, shared JavaScript runtime, can`t define <Runtimes> element

Tags: javascript, excel, manifest, add-in, add-on

We are developing an Excel add-on and trying to make it 'working long'. Now it starts to work when its tab is opened, but we would like to run it when the document is loaded and then keep add-on working.
As I understood, this approach can help:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/configure-your-add-in-to-use-a-shared-runtime

bu when I start to define the manifest:

```
...
<Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="Workbook">
        <Runtimes>
          <Runtime resid="KI.Taskpane.UrlMain" lifetime="long" />
        </Runtimes>
        
        <DesktopFormFactor>
        ...
```

and then 'publish' the manifest - MS VS 2017 reports the error:

The element 'Host' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides' has invalid child element 'Runtimes' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides'.

List of possible elements expected: 'DesktopFormFactor' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides'.

What can I do to fix it?
thanks for suggestions.

PS:
here is MS Doc about 'runtimes'
https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/runtimes

Comment: seems, my VS template was too old or kind of. here is a solution found (yet committed file requires small XML fixes) https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/issues/2392

Answer (score -1, accepted):

seems my VS template was too old or kind of. here is a solution found (yet committed file requires small XML fixes)

https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/issues/2392

Comment: Link only answers :(

Answer (score 0):

Find the file `TaskPaneAppVersionOverridesV1_0.xsd`

For me that was --> `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Xml\Schemas\1033\`

Replace with this file --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-owemxml/82e93ec5-de22-42a8-86e3-353c8336aa40

```
 <xs:schema id="TaskPaneAppVersionOverrides" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <xs:import schemaLocation="OfficeAppBasicTypesV1_0.xsd" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"/>
   <xs:complexType name="ShowTaskpane">
     <xs:complexContent>
       <xs:extension base="Action">
         <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element name="TaskpaneId" type="bt:ShortString" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
           <xs:element name="SourceLocation" type="bt:URLResourceReference" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
           <xs:element name="Title" type="bt:ShortResourceReference" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
         </xs:sequence>
       </xs:extension>
     </xs:complexContent>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="ExecuteFunction">
     <xs:complexContent>
       <xs:extension base="Action">
         <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element name="FunctionName" type="bt:LongString" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         </xs:sequence>
       </xs:extension>
     </xs:complexContent>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="Action" abstract="true"/>
   <xs:complexType name="Supertip">
     <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="Title" type="bt:ShortResourceReference" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
       <xs:element name="Description" type="bt:LongResourceReference" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
     </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="UIControl" abstract="true">
     <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="OverriddenByRibbonApi" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" default="false"/>
       <xs:element name="Label" type="bt:ShortResourceReference" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
       <xs:element name="Supertip" type="Supertip" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
     </xs:sequence>
     <xs:attribute name="id" type="bt:ShortString" use="required"/>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="UIControlWithIcon" abstract="true">
     <xs:complexContent>
       <xs:extension base="UIControl">
         <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element name="Icon" type="bt:IconList" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         </xs:sequence>
       </xs:extension>
     </xs:complexContent>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="UIControlWithOptionalIcon" abstract="true">
     <xs:complexContent>
       <xs:extension base="UIControl">
         <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element name="Icon" type="bt:IconList" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
         </xs:sequence>
       </xs:extension>
     </xs:complexContent>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="Button">
     <xs:complexContent>
       <xs:extension base="UIControlWithIcon">
         <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element name="Action" type="Action" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
           <xs:element name="Enabled" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" default="true"/>
         </xs:sequence>
       </xs:extension>
     </xs:complexContent>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="MenuItem">
     <xs:complexContent>
       <xs:extension base="UIControlWithOptionalIcon">
         <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element name="Action" type="Action" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
           <xs:element name="Enabled" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" default="true"/>
         </xs:sequence>
       </xs:extension>
     </xs:complexContent>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="MenuItems">
     <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="Item" type="MenuItem" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
     </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="Menu">
     <xs:complexContent>
       <xs:extension base="UIControlWithIcon">
         <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element name="Items" type="MenuItems" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
         </xs:sequence>
       </xs:extension>
     </xs:complexContent>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="Group">
     <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="OverriddenByRibbonApi" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" default="false"/>
       <xs:element name="Label" type="bt:ShortResourceReference" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
       <xs:element name="Icon" type="bt:IconList" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
       <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
         <xs:element name="Control" type="UIControl"/>
         <xs:element name="OfficeControl" type="OfficeControl"/>
       </xs:choice>
     </xs:sequence>
     <xs:attribute name="id" type="bt:ShortString" use="required"/>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="Tab" abstract="true">
     <xs:attribute name="id" type="bt:ShortString" use="required"/>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="OfficeMenu">
     <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="Control" type="UIControl" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
     </xs:sequence>
     <xs:attribute name="id" type="bt:ShortString" use="required"/>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="OfficeTab">
     <xs:complexContent>
       <xs:extension base="Tab">
         <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element name="Group" type="Group" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         </xs:sequence>
       </xs:extension>
     </xs:complexContent>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="CustomTab">
     <xs:complexContent>
       <xs:extension base="Tab">
         <xs:sequence>
           <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
             <xs:element name="Group" type="Group"/>
             <xs:element name="OfficeGroup" type="OfficeGroup"/>
           </xs:choice>
           <xs:element name="Label" type="bt:ShortResourceReference" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
           <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
             <xs:element name="InsertBefore" type="bt:ShortString"/>
             <xs:element name="InsertAfter" type="bt:ShortString"/>
           </xs:choice>
         </xs:sequence>
       </xs:extension>
     </xs:complexContent>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="OfficeControl">
     <xs:attribute name="id" type="bt:ShortString" use="required"/>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="OfficeGroup">
     <xs:attribute name="id" type="bt:ShortString" use="required"/>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="Script">
     <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="SourceLocation" type="bt:URLResourceReference" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
     </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="Page">
     <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="SourceLocation" type="bt:URLResourceReference" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
     </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="Metadata">
     <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="SourceLocation" type="bt:URLResourceReference" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
     </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="ExtensionPoint" abstract="true"/>
   <xs:complexType name="CommandSurfaceExtensionPoint" abstract="true">
     <xs:complexContent>
       <xs:extension base="ExtensionPoint">
         <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element name="OfficeTab" type="OfficeTab" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
           <xs:element name="CustomTab" type="CustomTab" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         </xs:sequence>
       </xs:extension>
     </xs:complexContent>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="PrimaryCommandSurface">
     <xs:complexContent>
       <xs:extension base="CommandSurfaceExtensionPoint"/>
     </xs:complexContent>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="ContextMenu">
     <xs:complexContent>
       <xs:extension base="ExtensionPoint">
         <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element name="OfficeMenu" type="OfficeMenu" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         </xs:sequence>
       </xs:extension>
     </xs:complexContent>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="CustomFunctions">
     <xs:complexContent>
       <xs:extension base="ExtensionPoint">
         <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element name="Script" type="Script" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
           <xs:element name="Page" type="Page" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
           <xs:element name="Metadata" type="Metadata" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
           <xs:element name="Namespace" type="bt:ShortResourceReference" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
         </xs:sequence>
       </xs:extension>
     </xs:complexContent>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="GetStarted">
     <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="Title" type="bt:ShortResourceReference" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
       <xs:element name="Description" type="bt:LongResourceReference" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
       <xs:element name="LearnMoreUrl" type="bt:URLResourceReference" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
     </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="FormFactor">
     <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="GetStarted" type="GetStarted" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
       <xs:element name="FunctionFile" type="bt:URLResourceReference" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
       <xs:element name="ExtensionPoint" type="ExtensionPoint" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
     </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="AllFormFactors">
     <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="ExtensionPoint" type="CustomFunctions" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
     </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="RuntimeOverride">
     <xs:attribute name="resid" type="bt:ShortString" use="required"/>
     <xs:attribute name="type" type="bt:ShortString" use="required"/>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="Runtime">
     <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="Override" type="RuntimeOverride" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
     </xs:sequence>
     <xs:attribute name="resid" type="bt:ShortString" use="required"/>
     <xs:attribute name="lifetime" type="bt:ShortString" use="optional"/>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="Runtimes">
     <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
       <xs:element name="Runtime" type="Runtime"/>
     </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="Host" abstract="true">
     <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="Runtimes" type="Runtimes" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
       <xs:element name="AllFormFactors" type="AllFormFactors" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
     </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="Workbook">
     <xs:complexContent>
       <xs:extension base="Host">
         <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element name="DesktopFormFactor" type="FormFactor" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
         </xs:sequence>
       </xs:extension>
     </xs:complexContent>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="Document">
     <xs:complexContent>
       <xs:extension base="Host">
         <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element name="DesktopFormFactor" type="FormFactor" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
         </xs:sequence>
       </xs:extension>
     </xs:complexContent>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="Notebook">
     <xs:complexContent>
       <xs:extension base="Host">
         <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element name="DesktopFormFactor" type="FormFactor" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
         </xs:sequence>
       </xs:extension>
     </xs:complexContent>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="Presentation">
     <xs:complexContent>
       <xs:extension base="Host">
         <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element name="DesktopFormFactor" type="FormFactor" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
         </xs:sequence>
       </xs:extension>
     </xs:complexContent>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="Hosts">
     <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
       <xs:element name="Host" type="Host"/>
     </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="WebApplicationScopes">
     <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
       <xs:element name="Scope" type="bt:LongString"/>
     </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="WebApplicationInfo">
     <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
       <xs:element name="Id" type="bt:UUID" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
       <xs:element name="Resource" type="bt:LongString" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
       <xs:element name="Scopes" type="WebApplicationScopes" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
     </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="EquivalentAddins">
     <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
       <xs:element name="EquivalentAddin" type="EquivalentAddin"/>
     </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="EquivalentAddin">
     <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
       <xs:element name="ProgId" type="bt:LongString" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
       <xs:element name="DisplayName" type="bt:LongString" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
       <xs:element name="FileName" type="bt:LongString" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
       <xs:element name="Type" type="bt:ShortString" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
     </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="VersionOverridesV1_0">
     <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="Description" type="bt:LongResourceReference" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
       <xs:element name="Requirements" type="bt:Requirements" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
       <xs:element name="Hosts" type="Hosts" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
       <xs:element name="Resources" type="bt:Resources" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
       <xs:element name="WebApplicationInfo" type="WebApplicationInfo" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
       <xs:element name="EquivalentAddins" type="EquivalentAddins" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
       <xs:any id="VersionOverrides" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides/1.1" processContents="lax"/>
     </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:element name="VersionOverrides" type="VersionOverridesV1_0"/>
 </xs:schema>
```